# How to compile Qt with Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, compilation

I created a Qt programme, I can compile it without problem manuelly with Visual Studio (using Add-In) but when I try to compile it with coding I have a problem. The problem is

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3. [C:\foo.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\foo.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\foo.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3. [C:\foo.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

How can I solve the problem, please help me…

Error:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 03.12.2013 11:35:49.
Project "C:\foo.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3. [C:\foo.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\foo.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\foo.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(CustomBuild target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3. [C:\foo.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.14
```

Comment: If you show the actual error that occurs we might be able to help you. My guess is you don't have the Qt tools in PATH. But this is just what my crystal ball is telling me.

Comment: I can compile the program manuelly witout problem. I am sharing the error

Answer (score 3):

This message:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

in the current context tells me that the build program can't find `moc.exe` and `uic.exe`. You need to add `C:\Qt\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\bin` or whatever directory contains `qmake.exe`, `moc.exe`, `uic.exe` and other Qt programs to PATH by doing:

```
set PATH=C:\Qt\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: which program i need to add? Qt program? or other c++ program (which compile Qt program)?

Comment: @citi Qt comes with programs like `moc` and `uic` that preprocess your source files to create extra source files, which are then compiled as part of the build process. The ones you need should all be in the same location (I gave the example for my Qt 5.1.1 installation through the installer's default settings).

Comment: I have C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\msvc2010\bin    inside Projects/Properties/Configuration Properties/Debugging/Command.